# How to pass dynamic value to upload form in HTML from javascript?

Tags: jquery, html

I have Upload form:

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="A">
    <br>
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfileInput" type="file" /><input type="submit" value="Upload File" /><img src="/invite/images/Input.gif" style="margin-left: 140px">
</form>
```

You can see I pass `value="A"`

How can I put instead `"A"` some function that returns value?

Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="getSomeValue()">
```

**JS**

```
...

function  getSomeValue(){
  return localStorage['some Data'];
}
...
```

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type">
```

With jquery you can do:

```
 jQuery('#type').val('whatever');
```

Or, without adding `id`:

```
 jQuery('input[name="type"]').val('whatever');
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the value attribute:

```
$(selector).val()
```

Set the value attribute:

```
$(selector).val(value)
```

Set the value attribute using a function:

```
$(selector).val(function(index,currentvalue))
```